# Looping Over lots of User data to send Mail in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to send mail to users who have not updated there profile. And such Total user are more than 100k. Mail will be personalised and it will be sent from firebase cloud function.

So to do that i have to bring all such user data from Firebase and loop through them to send mail. However i feel this is not a good idea. Because problem which i feel is that if there is a million or more data and looping over it and sending mail will be time consuming. So  if any one from user updates his profile while functions is looping over data. He or she will receive mail even if he or she has updated profile.

What will be the best way to achieve this? #AskFirebase

Comment: You're saying two conflicting things.  First, you're saying that you want to send email to "all users".  Then you're saying you want to send email to only users "on certain conditions".  If it's not really all users, then construct a query that best filters the list of users to only those that meet the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out issue. I have made separate fields for such user. But problem is same. What if such user are more than 100k.

Comment: bring range of some user then sending mail will work i think. But then problem is  bringing 100 user from 1000 user will work good. But 100 from more then  10 lakhs user will be to slow i think. May be i have to write code which decide the range based on number of such user.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to access that data and do it on a server instead on the device itself

Comment: @ Farmaan Elahi. Please read and understand my question. I am already using cloud functions

Comment: You can use order by value on the query to order the item up to the last timestamp you want the snapshot for